# Making a for loop or a function in r to iterate over two lists

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I would like to do the same 2 functions for different sets of variables, each from a different list.

Example:

```r
clusters_group5 <- c(cluster1_group5, cluster2_group5, cluster3_group5)
celltypes <- c(celltype_1, celltype_2, celltype_3) 

#finding the # and % of genes that match across the two gene lists for cluster 1 in group 5
sum(cluster1_group5_samples6and7 %in% celltype_1)
mean(cluster1_group5_samples6and7 %in% celltype_1)

sum(cluster1_group5_samples6and7 %in% celltype_2)
mean(cluster1_group5_samples6and7 %in% celltype_2)


#finding the # and % of genes that match across the two gene lists for cluster 2 in group 5
sum(cluster2_group5_samples6and7 %in% celltype_1)
mean(cluster2_group5_samples6and7 %in% celltype_1)

sum(cluster2_group5_samples6and7 %in% celltype_2)
mean(cluster2_group5_samples6and7 %in% celltype_2)
```

Could I automate this or run this quicker using a for loop or a function?

I tried to do something like this:

```r
output <- function(list1, list2) {
  for (i in list 1, j in list2) {
    sum(i %in% j)
    mean(i %in% j)
  }

output(clusters_group5, celltypes)
```

but it seems that the for loop can only take in one list at a time.

Appreciate any help with this!

Comment: A `for` loop can only *iterate* over one thing at a time. If you want to iterate *in parallel* (1st item of list1 and 1st item of list2, 2nd item of list1 and 2nd item of list2, ...) then a single for loop works well. If you want to iterate *in series* to get every combination of items from list1 and list2 then you can use a nested loop: `for(i in list1) { for(j in list2) { .... }}`

Comment: If you need more help, making your example reproducible by sharing just a little sample of your inputs would help a lot.